# How can I change the form action depending on javascript being enabled?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that I want to default to calling a javascript ajax function to get the output. If the user doesn't have javascript enabled, I need to be able to recognize that and change the form action to a php page. Any idea on how to do this?

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="javascript:search();">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="search">Search</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

`search()` will get the form input and get the output through ajax without reloading the page. If javascript is not enabled, I will need to change the action to just `search.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default set action to `search.php`

if client JavaScript is enabled below code will change action

```
$(function () {
    $('.form-inline').prop('action', 'javascript:search();');
});
```